# How to avoid repetition of a column value in My-Sql

Tags: php, mysql

[This is my result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDNvu.png)

I need to avoid repetition of the field Total, but I need all those data in all other fields, can anyone please help to attain the result!?

**Here is my SQL Query**

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(credit.amount) 
  FROM credit,customers 
  WHEREcredit.date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' 
  AND credit.cus_id=customers.id) AS Total,
  credit.amount, credit.date,   
  customers.name 
FROM customers, credit 
WHERE credit.date BETWEEN' 2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' 
AND credit.cus_id=customers.id 
ORDER BY credit.date
```

Comment: Provide table structure with example data as formatted text not as image... And also provide expected output as formatted text..

Comment: Usually you will get all selected columns for all rows, but maybe I am misunderstanding something here. Is the data going to a script (PHP, .NET, ...) - could you sort it there and/or make two separate queries?

Comment: yes its  going to a php page, i need to avoid the seperate query thats y  i asked

Comment: I cannot well understand why you inserted a subquery that returns always the same result. Are you sure you cannot avoid this field and send it to a separate query?

Comment: yes i can avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a row counter and use it with a conditional function IF. If the row number is <=1 it runs the subquery otherwise it prints an empty varchar ''.

As I said in the comment, I will consider to extract the subquery and run it in a separate query, then add its result to the first row with the application.

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,
  IF(@rank>1,'',(SELECT SUM(credit.amount) 
  FROM credit,customers 
  WHEREcredit.date BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' 
  AND credit.cus_id=customers.id)) AS Total,
  credit.amount, credit.date,   
  customers.name 
FROM customers, credit 
WHERE credit.date BETWEEN' 2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-31' 
AND credit.cus_id=customers.id 
ORDER BY credit.date
```

Comment: Rank is just a row counter, like ROW_NUMBER of SQL server. I need it because he want the subquery only in the first row

Comment: NO am getting an error anyways but I took the result in PHP by taking the result outside the loop

Comment: If your using php you cannot simply paste this code because there are two queries. Please try with phpmyadmin or dbfiddle. Anyway is a good choice to move the subquery away.

Comment: I used PHP-my-admin but it gives the error, using of sub query is much faster ryt?

Comment: Maybe there is a version problem. I tried with Mysql 5.7 but will check again.
If you have thousands of rows you're querying n-1 unuseful subqueries and you are saved only by the cache system of dbms.

Comment: ok! how can I take the sum of amount in one-month duration from a table consider am having amount field and date field?? i need the sum of amount in current month

Comment: Please edit your questions or start a new one. The solution can be grouping results by Month and year.

Comment: shall we go for a chat?

Comment: I'm going out of office now , sorry, but you can start a chat and I will answer when I can.